# Do math on CSH or SH only with string variables

Tags: string, variables, math, sh, csh

I have string variables MIN and SEC (minute and seconds).

```
MIN = "1"
SEC = "34"
```

I want to do calculations on these.

> TOTSEC = MIN*60 + SEC

I tried:

expr $SEC + $MIN * 60

Result:

> expr: non-numeric argument

Let it be known I am running busybox on a custom microcomputer and so have no access to bash,bc, and that other solution provides.

Comment: Does `\*` instead of `*` to avoid being treated like a glob work?

Comment: Same error is output after i use \\*

Comment: csh or sh? They're quite different.

Comment: `expr $SEC + $MIN \* 60` works for me in dash.

Comment: yes, please confirm csh or sh, as you need to use `set MIN = 3` syntax in `csh`. Maybe you want to remove references to csh, unless that is what you want. Good luck.

Comment: in `sh` (bash, etc). the correct syntax is `MIN=1`. (no spaces around `=`). AND in all  shells, all variable values are treated as strings. You only need to dbl-quote in an assigment like that if your value has spaces, i.e. `word="a b c"` . Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `sh`, by which I'll assume you mean a [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html), your best option is to use [Arithmetic Expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04):

```
$ MIN=1
$ SEC=34
$ TOTSEC=$(( MIN * 60 + SEC ))
$ printf '%d\n' "$TOTSEC"
94
```

In `csh` however, the built-in math works quite differently:

```
% set MIN = 1
% set SEC = 34
% @ TOTSEC = ( $MIN * 60 + $SEC )
% printf '%d\n' "$TOTSEC"
94
```

According to the man page, the `@` command permits numeric calculations to be performed and the result assigned to a variable.

Note that the `expr` command is external to the shell, so it should be usable from either one.

In `sh`:

```
$ TOTSEC=$(expr "$MIN" \* 60 + "$SEC")
```

And in `csh`:

```
% set TOTSEC = `expr "$MIN" \* 60 + "$SEC"`
```

Note: your `sh` may not be POSIX compliant. Most likely, it's [ash](/questions/tagged/ash), which is the ancestor of `dash` and FreeBSD's `/bin/sh`. You'll need to test in your environment.

Comment: Hi pls note that MIN=1 is not correct. It is actually string like this. MIN="1"

Comment: @GeneCode there's no numeric type in bash. `MIN=1` is exactly the same as `MIN="1"` or `MIN='1'`